# From an array remove duplicate data behalf of another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I have two arrays one is an original array and second is the copy of an original array. I put some new items in an array and update some of one  and want to compare it with copy array and want to eliminate those items which are in copy array and keep those items where `Id = null`

```
 var original = [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "BrandConstruct": 265,
        "YearPlanData": "a"
    },
    {   "Id": 2,
        "BrandConstruct": 236,
        "YearPlanData": "c"
    },
    {   "Id": 3,
        "BrandConstruct": 376,
        "YearPlanData": "b"
    },
    {   "Id": null,
        "BrandConstruct": 476,
        "YearPlanData": "e"
    }, 
    {   "Id": null,
        "BrandConstruct": 576,
        "YearPlanData": "f"
    }

]

    var copy = [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "BrandConstruct": 165,
        "YearPlanData": "a"
    },
    {   "Id": 2,
        "BrandConstruct": 236,
        "YearPlanData": "c"
    },
    {   "Id": 3,
        "BrandConstruct": 376,
        "YearPlanData": "b"
    }

]
```

These are two arrays with properties Id, BrandConstruct, YearPlanData I add the new item or may be multiple items where all will have  Id = null and other properties will have any data or may be duplicate data so I want to eliminate duplicate data     using copy array but keep data where Id = null
so I want this type of result after comparison and it must be work on IE

```
    var original = [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "BrandConstruct": 265,
        "YearPlanData": "a"
    },

    {   "Id": null,
        "BrandConstruct": 476,
        "YearPlanData": "e"
    }, 
    {   "Id": null,
        "BrandConstruct": 576,
        "YearPlanData": "f"
    }

]
```

Comment: Is this a specific angularjs question or a general js question?

Comment: I am using Angular1 and using handsontable table plugin so I fetch data from server side and make an array and make updates and again send this table data in the form of array so problem is I do not want those rows which are unchanged just new inserted and updated @Brakebien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but I think you should wait for a better solution.

```js
var original = [{
  "Id": 1,
  "BrandConstruct": 265,
  "YearPlanData": "a"
}, {
  "Id": 2,
  "BrandConstruct": 236,
  "YearPlanData": "c"
}, {
  "Id": 3,
  "BrandConstruct": 376,
  "YearPlanData": "b"
}, {
  "Id": null,
  "BrandConstruct": 476,
  "YearPlanData": "e"
}, {
  "Id": null,
  "BrandConstruct": 576,
  "YearPlanData": "f"
}];

var copy = [{
  "Id": 1,
  "BrandConstruct": 165,
  "YearPlanData": "a"
}, {
  "Id": 2,
  "BrandConstruct": 236,
  "YearPlanData": "c"
}, {
  "Id": 3,
  "BrandConstruct": 376,
  "YearPlanData": "b"
}];
copy = copy.map(function(el) {
  return JSON.stringify(el);
});

original = original.map(function(el) {
  return JSON.stringify(el);
}).filter(function(els) {
  return copy.indexOf(els) == -1;
}).map(function(s) {
  return JSON.parse(s);
});
console.log(original);
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
const newOriginal = original.filter(obj => {
    return !copy.find(copyObj => JSON.stringify(copyObj) === JSON.stringify(obj))
});
```

This should work at Internet Explorer:

```js
const newOriginal = original.filter(function(obj) {
    return !copy.filter(function(copyObj) { return JSON.stringify(copyObj) === JSON.stringify(obj)}).length
});
```

Comment: it is working but Arrow (=>) not working on IE so it shows error on IE @Nir Berko

Comment: Thanks, it is working perfectly on all browsers @Nir Berko

Comment: Sorry but this code also throw error on IE @Nir Berko

Comment: Check the Image I just add it @Nir Berko

Comment: If I use this code then also there is shown a "unspecified error" on <! DOCTYPE html> on IE 11

Comment: @Anshul, Its seems like a different problem in angular, i am not an angular developer so i cant help you with that. I think you should make a new question about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the `original` array, and push the elements that are not belonged to the `copy` array to a new array.

```js
function isInArray(item, array) {
  return JSON.stringify(array).indexOf(JSON.stringify(item)) > -1
}

function getFilteredArray(original, copy) {
  var newOriginal = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
    var item = original[i];
    if (!isInArray(item, copy) || item.id === null) newOriginal.push(item);
  }

  return newOriginal;
}

var original = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "BrandConstruct": 265,
    "YearPlanData": "a"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "BrandConstruct": 236,
    "YearPlanData": "c"
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "BrandConstruct": 376,
    "YearPlanData": "b"
  },
  {
    "Id": null,
    "BrandConstruct": 476,
    "YearPlanData": "e"
  },
  {
    "Id": null,
    "BrandConstruct": 576,
    "YearPlanData": "f"
  }

]

var copy = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "BrandConstruct": 165,
    "YearPlanData": "a"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "BrandConstruct": 236,
    "YearPlanData": "c"
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "BrandConstruct": 376,
    "YearPlanData": "b"
  }

]

console.log(getFilteredArray(original, copy));
```

Comment: But I also want to keep those elements where Id = null @phuwin

Comment: I edited my answer. I added in the check if the id of the item is null, it will also be pushed to the new array.

Answer (score 1):

This is for arrray of objects, you can push them into an empty array when the index of the attribute you are searching for is not found, creating a new array of the unique values:

```
   for (var key in array_of_objects) {
     var index = empty_array.findIndex(x => x.attribute == array_of_objects.attribute)
        if (index === -1){
            empty_array.push(d);
        }
   }
```